# Regarding image load before full page

Tags: javascript, image, preload

probably there was topic before but unfortunately my solution still does not work. I want to achieve that my image would load before the full page, because right now I am getting black background FIRST instead of image (image loads after). Could you help me with that?

Here is my solution so far (but I am getting black background FIRST instead of image).

Code:

```
<script>
// Preload big parallax image

function preloadImage() {


  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image();
    var img_url = 'assets/images/masthead.jpeg';
    img.src = img_url;
    resolve(img_url);
  });

}



$(document).ready(function(){
  preloadImage().then(function(fromResolve){
    $('.ui.inverted.segment.masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + fromResolve + ')');
  });
});
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
// Preload big parallax image

function preloadImage() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image();
    var img_url = 'assets/images/masthead.jpeg';
    img.onload = function(x){resolve(img_url);};
    img.onerror = function(x){reject([err,img_url]);};
    img.src = img_url;
  });

}
preloadImage()//load the images first
.then(function(fromResolve){
  $(document).ready(//wait for document to be ready
    function(){
      $('.ui.inverted.segment.masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + fromResolve + ')');      
    }
  )
})
.catch(//if something went wrong
  function(info){
    console.log("image load failed because:",info[0],"url:",info[1])
  }
);
```

Comment: Unfortunatey still same firstly i see black background and then after 1-2sec image appears :/

Comment: @user2204367 Do you want to hide the element until the image is loaded? The code as is should load the image as soon as possible (if the script is in the head tag). Also if the image isn't cached then pre loading is useless because setting the css background will just load the image again from server.

Comment: Probably you know those websites with big images, so when open the site it loads all the images by giving you some kind of loading icon before, so you will enter the site all the images are completely loaded, because right now I am on the site and I still see how the image is still loading (even in frames).

Comment: Maybe ('$imgid').load(function(){
}); would solve the issue?